# cannot read property of undefined (reading define)

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

so i am tryin to make use of sequelize in the project i am  building and i keep getting this error and yet all my dependencies have been added to the project

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Eddy\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:666    
    options = Utils.merge(_.cloneDeep(globalOptions.define), options);
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'define')       
    at Function.init (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Eddy\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:666:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Eddy\models\User.js:6:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)       
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)  
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)        
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Eddy\server.js:13:14)  
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)       
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

my code looks like this

```
const {Model, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../server');

class User extends Model {}

User.init ({
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    full_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        date_created: DataTypes.DATE,
        date_updated: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    user_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        date_created: DataTypes.DATE,
        date_updated: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        date_created: DataTypes.DATE,
        date_updated: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    address: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        date_created: DataTypes.DATE,
        date_updated: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    phone_number: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        date_created: DataTypes.DATE,
        date_updated: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        date_created: DataTypes.DATE,
        date_updated: DataTypes.DATE
    },
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user_info'
})


module.exports = User;
```

i expected to get a result that says 'connection to database has been successful' in the console but this error keeps popping up

Comment: The error message is clear. `globalOptions` is undefined. Please debug it.